# Getting from Astrakhan, Russia to Aktau, Kazakhstan

Tags: russia, astrakhan, kazakhstan, aktau

I'm in Astrakhan, Russia. There's very little information out there on buses or trains to use to eventually get to Aktau, Kazakhstan.

[bahn.de](http://www.bahn.de/p/view/index.shtml) shows a 75 hour train with 3 changes, so I have no idea what crazy route that's taking as it's really not that far.

I think in theory I can get to Atyrau first, and then a connection from there to Aktau, but this is all in theory only; I may just have to wing it when I get there - unless you guys can help with some more info? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this conversation](http://www.aktau-forum.com/archive/index.php/t-2619.html), there is no ferries across the Caspian sea on this route (except some rumours I don't believe to), and all people suggests two types of trip:

1. [Plane](http://www.scat.kz/) company "Skat", phone in Astrakhan: 8(8512) 39 03 62, 8(8512) 39 41 95
2. [Train](http://www.tutu.ru/poezda/view_d.php?np=8e46920a) from Astrakhan to [Mangystau](http://maps.google.ru/maps?q=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%83,%20%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C,%20%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%85%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD&hl=ru&ie=UTF8&sll=55.354135,40.297852&sspn=13.071421,29.926758&client=firefox-a&geocode=FcS9mgIdnywPAw&z=11) (20km from Aktau)

I think the second one is exactly you are looking for.

Comment: No way, that's WAY faster than anything I've seen (current best was going to be 30 hours).  Off to the station now to see when the trains go. Thanks!

Comment: Train is not fast - it will be over 3 days in a journey.

Comment: Actually that link goes to Мангышлак (Mangysluk (spelling)), which is different to Mangystau (SE of Mangystau) - but still about 40km from Aktau).  Fairly sure - my Cyrillic is still strugglin ;)  I realise you're from Russia, so you may be able to explain if I'm reading it wrong.

Comment: re not fast - just realising now I'd misread it.

Comment: average speed of 16km/hr.  Good grief that's slow.

Comment: Huh, if you look at the actual times station by station, at midnght there's a bug and it jumps 24 hours. Actual time from 14.28 Day 0 to 09.10 on Day 2 - that's less than 1 day 19 hours.  Phew!

Comment: And thank you :) Despite my very little Russian, I was able to buy a ticket to Aktau from Astrakhan, primarily because she seemed to be saying lots, but I heard Mangystau and was  "Oh, I know what she means!".  Leave tomorrow afternoon :)

Comment: Your Cyrillic is good, and I'm sorry for that miss in train. Hope that helps.

Comment: I wish you a good trip